# Passar context em contextos assíncronos Flutter

Tags: flutter, assincronismo

to tentando melhorar meu código declarando uns Utils para poder acessar em todo lugar do código o problema e que ta reclamando sobre não usar o context em um contexto assíncrono e não sei bem como resolver alem de que queria usar um nome melhor se possível, pois uso pra autenticação e formulários. Um outro problema que to tentando solucionar e caso eu esteja sem internet, queria conseguir tratar isso também até criei uma função mas queria saber quais as melhores praticas para tratar isso e inclusive a função ta com o mesmo warning de não usar o context em um contexto assíncrono:

```dart
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  LoginPageState createState() => LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool _isObscured = true;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };

  Future<void> _submit() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState?.save();

    AuthProvider authViewModel = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
    try {
      await authViewModel.loginWithEmail(
        _authData['email']!,
        _authData['password']!,
      );
      Modular.to.navigate('/splash/');
    } catch (error) {
      AppUtils.showErrorMessage(context, error.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}

class AppUtils {
  static Future<void> showErrorMessage(
      BuildContext context, String error) async {
    return AwesomeDialog(
      context: context,
      dialogType: DialogType.error,
      animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
      headerAnimationLoop: true,
      title: 'error_occurred'.i18n(),
      desc: error,
      btnOkIcon: Icons.cancel,
      btnOkColor: Colors.red,
    ).show();
  }

  static Future<void> checkConnectivity(
      BuildContext context, VoidCallback operation) async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      showErrorMessage(context, 'no_internet'.i18n());
    } else {
      operation();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você verá um *warning* que diz

> Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps

toda vez que mencionar um objeto `BuildContext` após usar `await` numa chamada assíncrona. O `context` do Flutter diz respeito ao contexto **atual** do app. Ou seja, de cada tela/popup que está sendo mostrado neste exato momento.

Agora, vamos imaginar uma coisa. O usuário, cujo dispositivo não tem acesso à internet, entra numa tela e vê um *loader*. Pode ser que leve uns cinco segundos para que `checkConnectivity` (ou qualquer chamada assíncrona) retorne algum resultado. Quando isso acontecer, o usuário pode já ter saído da tela (contexto) em que ele estava quando `checkConnectivity` foi chamado.

O que vai acontecer na sequência é que sua função tentará chamar `showErrorMessage(context, 'no_internet'.i18n());`, que é uma operação dependente de um contexto que não é mais válido e já foi desmontado assim que o usuário saiu daquela tela. O que você quer fazer, na verdade, é mostrar a mensagem de erro *se* o usuário ainda estiver naquela tela. E para testar se esse é o caso, usamos `context.mounted`.

Toda vez que você for realizar interrupções assíncronas (`await`) antes de usar um `context`, você deve checar se o contexto ainda está montado:

```
  static Future<void> checkConnectivity(
      BuildContext context, VoidCallback operation) async {
    final connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

    if (context.mounted && connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      showErrorMessage(context, 'no_internet'.i18n());
    }

    else {
      operation();
    }
  }
```